# DB selecting the newest ID is not the latest insert value

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I need to select latest insert data from MariaDB

My MariaDB version 10.1

here is my table

```
name     Index    type      default
------------------------------------------
key      Primary  BIGINT    AUTO_INCREMENT
dateTime UNIQUE   DATETIME  N/A
roadkey  N/A      BOLB      N/A

key    dateTime            roadkey
38438  2016-10-08 16:13:00 .......
38437  2017-01-13 03:33:00.......
```

and I execute the following command

```
SELECT `key`,dateTime,COLUMN_GET(roadKey,'64000I01580' as char) AS 'roadkey' 
FROM dynamic_datetimetable 
WHERE `key` <= (SELECT MAX(`key`) FROM dynamic_datetimetable)
ORDER BY `key` DESC 
LIMIT 0,3;
```

or I change condition to

```
WHERE `key` <= 38438
```

both show me this:

```
key    dateTime            roadkey
32145  2017-01-11 13:45:00 .......
32144  2016-10-05 09:22:00 .......
32143  2017-01-11 13:44:00 .......
```

but the latest insert key is 38438 not 32145.

And I can select 38438 if the condition is

```
WHERE `key` = 38438
```

I wonder know whether I miss something to update DB record?
Or I have wrong conception about DB?

Comment: Why do you need the `WHERE` clause? Isn't `key` always less than or equal to the max value?

Comment: why not WHERE `key` = (SELECT MAX(`key`) FROM dynamic_datetimetable) and why the LIMIT at the end?

Comment: No, if I delete `WHERE` it show the same wrong answer

Comment: @isaace He wants the highest 3 rows, not just the highest row.

Comment: Sounds like the index might be corrupted, try repairing it.

Comment: SELECT max(`key`) FROM dynamic_datetimetable this show me 38794, but if I use WHERE `key` < 38794 -> the biggest key still is 32145

Comment: Columns named "key" or "datetime" often lead to some troubles... The query should work. I have no fiddle for MariaDB. With MySQL, it works : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pf6JEXb21KRFLqLJ2qjFr4/0

Comment: You could try `optimize table dynamic_datetimetable`. It may fix some issues with your indexing. If that doesn't fix it, I don't know what the issue is. You also don't need the `WHERE` for this query. The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` is enough to get the desired records.

Comment: @Genu If i use keyword as column name, I can use **``**.
@CptMisery It seems not work for me. but thank you :).

Comment: Does it continue to fail if you remove `COLUMN_GET(...)` from the `SELECT` list?

Comment: It seems this error won't happen anymore, I restart the DB after I have tried any solution I can. And it works, but I can't Know what going on... thanks everyone